# "error C2015: too many characters in constant" for a char32_t literal

Tags: c++, unicode

`char32_t c = U'▁'` works under GCC and Clang, but fails under MSVC with the error

```
error C2015: too many characters in constant
```

`U'\u2581'` works, but is this a compiler bug? Microsoft's [String and character literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160) documentation doesn't seem to say anything about it not being supported, but maybe I've missed something relevant.

Comment: This might have something to do with the source character set that the CPP file is treated as. What character encoding is the source file saved with?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm UTF-8.

Comment: If I compile that line in a file saved as "UTF-8", it compiles fine. If I use "UTF-8-no-bom" (as my editor calls it; there is no byte order marking at the start of the file) I get that error.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ah, and 1) VS Code goes the other way; "UTF-8" and "UTF-8 with BOM"; 2) according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8, "Microsoft compilers and interpreters, and many pieces of software on Microsoft Windows such as Notepad treat the BOM as a required magic number rather than use heuristics." even though it isn't recommended. Looks like this is the answer; thanks!

Comment: U+2581 is 3 bytes in UTF-8: `0xE2 0x96 0x81`. If the compiler doesn’t know the source file is UTF-8 then it will treat `U'▁'` as a multi-byte character literal, hence the error.

Comment: MSVC needs `/utf-8` compiler switch if source file has no BOM else assumes localized ANSI encoding, e.g. `Windows-1252` on US and Western European versions of Windows.

Answer (score 4):

@remy-lebeau and @mark-tolonen are correct.  I had this issue and adding the `/utf-8` compiler flag is what I needed.  My source file was using utf-8.  I am using VS 2022 (17.4.4).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=msvc-170